# My controller considers that my store id is the products id

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

My controlller can't read that the 'sample' is a store and not a product.
I have this Route on my web.php

```
    Route::get('{store}/products/{products}/edit', [
    'as'    => 'store.products.edit',
    'uses'  => 'ProductsController@edit',
    function($store) {
        $store = App\Models\Store::where('slug', $store)->firstOrFail();
    }
]);
```

and here is my ProductsController@edit

```
    public function edit($id)
{
    $product = Product::findOrFail($id);

    return view('view here', compact('product'));
}
```

when I run the url: http://127.0.0.1:8000/sample/products/022fe902-7f4d-4db1-b562-04a7eb9f5a68/edit

where sample is the {store} and 022fe902-7f4d-4db1-b562-04a7eb9f5a68 is the {product}

I get this error:

> No query results for model [App\Models\Product] sample

in my query:

> select * from `products` where `products`.`uuid` = 'sample' limit 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have 2 parameters, you should have them both in your controller in valid order, so you should have:

```
public function edit($store, $id)
{
    $product = Product::findOrFail($id);

    return view('view here', compact('product'));
}
```

Also probably you don't need here:

```
function($store) {
   $store = App\Models\Store::where('slug', $store)->firstOrFail();
}
```

for anything, but maybe in your controller you should do something like this:

```
$store = App\Models\Store::where('slug', $store)->firstOrFail();
$product = $store->products()->findOrFail($id);
```

Assuming you have product in this store and you would like to make sure that someone won't edit product that is assigned to different store.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I needed